# gRPC Web with nginx is throwing frame header malformed: reserved bits not zero

Tags: nginx, grpc-java, grpc-web

We have the following setup:

grpc-web -> nginx -> grpc-java service

When our grpc-java service receives the request, it's throwing the following exception
`StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: gRPC frame header malformed: reserved bits not zero`

The request from grpc-web looks like this

```
curl 'http://localhost:9091/com.personal.test.PrivateService/Execute' \
  -H 'Accept: application/grpc-web-text' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/grpc-web-text' \
  -H 'Origin: https://test.com' \
  -H 'Proxy-Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36 (Cypress)' \
  -H 'X-Cypress-Is-XHR-Or-Fetch: xhr' \
  -H 'X-Grpc-Web: 1' \
  -H 'X-User-Agent: grpc-web-javascript/0.1' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua;' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: ""' \
  --data-raw 'AAAAACgKJmdpdmVuIGEgc2ltcGxlIGhpZXJhcmNoeSB3aXRoIGN1c3RvbWVy' \
  --compressed
```

nginx(running in docker) has following config

```
events { }

http {
    server {
        listen 9091 http2;
        location / {
          grpc_pass grpc://host.docker.internal:9090;
          grpc_set_header Content-Type "application/grpc";
          grpc_set_header Proxy-Connection "";
          grpc_set_header x-forwarded-proto http;
          grpc_set_header grpc-accept-encoding identity;
    }
  }
}
```

grpc-java service(running on port 9090) is throwing following:

```
{"ts":"2023-09-11T19:57:16.186+02","logLevel":"DEBUG","thread":"grpc-nio-worker-ELG-3-5","logger":"io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler","message":"[id: 0xb46b7519, L:/127.0.0.1:9090 - R:/127.0.0.1:59453] INBOUND DATA: streamId=1 padding=0 endStream=true length=84 bytes=4141414141446f4b476d6470646d567549484e305a58416764326c306143427759584a68625756305a584a7a4567304b42485a68624445534257467a5a475a6e..."}

{"ts":"2023-09-11T19:57:16.189+02","logLevel":"WARN","thread":"grpc-nio-worker-ELG-3-5","logger":"io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerStream","message":"Exception processing message","stacktrace":"i.g.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: gRPC frame header malformed: reserved bits not zero\n\tat io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:529)\n\tat i.g.i.MessageDeframer.processHeader(MessageDeframer.java:382)\n\tat i.g.i.MessageDeframer.deliver(MessageDeframer.java:272)\n\tat i.g.i.MessageDeframer.request(MessageDeframer.java:162)\n\tat i.g.i.AbstractStream$TransportState$1RequestRunnable.run(AbstractStream.java:233)\n\tat i.g.n.s.i.g.n.NettyServerStream$TransportState$1.run(NettyServerStream.java:188)\n\tat i.g.n.s.i.n.u.c.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)\n\tat i.g.n.s.i.n.u.c.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java)\n\tat i.g.n.s.i.n.u.c.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)\n\tat i.g.n.s.i.n.u.c.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)\n\tat i.g.n.s.i.n.c.n.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:566)\n\tat i.g.n.s.i.n.u.c.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)\n\tat i.g.n.s.i.n.u.i.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)\n\tat i.g.n.s.i.n.u.c.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\n"}
```

Seems like nginx is not able to translate the grpc-web request to valid http2 header frame binary format - it's missing the reserved bits `(INBOUND DATA: streamId=1 padding=0 endStream=true length=84 bytes=4141414....)`

I was wondering if anyone made it possible to use the grpc-web with nginx and might have overcome the issue I encountered, thanks for any help

I tried using envoy instead of nginx and it worked fine

Comment: FYI please see updates here too :)
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/discussions/1322